# в месте [i+=1] пишет invalid syntax, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print, syntax, txt

```
import time
i=0
book = open('Leskov.txt', 'r')
str=book.read()
print(len(str))
while i<=27174:
    print(str[i+=1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, до использования while переменная i не определена. Первая ошибка.
Во-вторых, i+=1 эквивалентно i=i+1. Подумайте, разьве так можно писать в индексах?

Вот работающий пример, исправляйте свой по подобию:

```
str="123456"
i=0
while i<=4:
    print(str[i+1])
    i+=1
```

Результат работы:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: А в JS - можно)

Comment: Да в Питоне вроде тоже можно будет скоро, но пока нельзя )

Comment: Правильное поведение программы: обращение к массиву по индексу, потом инкремент индекса. Приращение сначала в индексе массива, потом инкремент может запутать человека, изучающего основы программирования, подать ему пример неправильного стиля.